# Send contact form to email address based on selection

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I have a contact form that has a dropdown to choose which department the enquiry should go to...

```
<form action="contact-send.php" id="callback" method="post">
    <ul>
    <li class="left">
    <label for="name"><span class="required">*</span> Your Name</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['name'] : '' ?>" placeholder="John Doe" required autofocus /></li>
    <li class="right">
    <label for="email"><span class="required">*</span> Email Address</label>
    <br>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['email'] : '' ?>" placeholder="johndoe@example.com" required /></li>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <li class="left">
    <label for="enquiry"><span class="required">*</span> Enquiry</label><br>
    <select id="enquiry" name="enquiry">
        <option value="Admin / Accounts enquiry" <?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['enquiry'] == 'Admin / Accounts enquiry') ? "selected='selected'" : '' ?>>Admin / Accounts enquiry</option>
        <option value="Plant Hire / Haulage / Recycling / Contract Earthworks" <?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['enquiry'] == 'Plant Hire / Haulage / Recycling / Contract Earthworks') ? "selected='selected'" : '' ?>>Plant Hire / Haulage / Recycling / Contract Earthworks</option>
        <option value="Waste Management / Skip Hire" <?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['enquiry'] == 'Waste Management / Skip Hire') ? "selected='selected'" : '' ?>>Waste Management / Skip Hire</option>
    </select></li>
    <li>
    <label for="message"><span class="required">*</span> Message</label><br />
    <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your message must be greater than 20 charcters" required data-minlength="20"><?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['message'] : '' ?></textarea>
    </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <p class="form-button right"><input class="submit" id="callback-submit" name="submit" value="Send" type="submit"></p>
</form>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to modify the following process script so that it sends the enquiry to a specified email address, depending on which department is selected...

```
<?php
function clean_input($input){
return strip_tags(trim($input));
}
if( isset($_POST) ){

    //form validation vars
    $formok = true;
    $errors = array();

    //sumbission data
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $date = date('d/m/Y');
    $time = date('H:i:s');

    //form data
    $name = clean_input($_POST['name']);
    $email = clean_input($_POST['email']);
    $enquiry = clean_input($_POST['enquiry']);
    $message = clean_input($_POST['message']);

    //validate form data

    //validate name is not empty
    if(empty($name)){
        $formok = false;
        $errors[] = "You have not entered a name";
    }

    //validate email address is not empty
    if(empty($email)){
        $formok = false;
        $errors[] = "You have not entered an email address";
    //validate email address is valid
    }elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $formok = false;
        $errors[] = "You have not entered a valid email address";
    }

    //validate message is not empty
    if(empty($message)){
        $formok = false;
        $errors[] = "You have not entered a message";
    }
    //validate message is greater than 20 charcters
    elseif(strlen($message) < 20){
        $formok = false;
        $errors[] = "Your message must be greater than 20 characters";
    }

    //send email if all is ok
    if($formok){
        ini_set("sendmail_from","EMAIL_ADDRESS"); 
        $headers = "From: EMAIL_ADDRESS" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

        $emailbody = "<p>You have received a new contact us enquiry.</p>
                      <p><strong>Name: </strong> {$name} </p>
                      <p><strong>Email: </strong> {$email} </p>
                      <p><strong>Enquiry: </strong> {$enquiry} </p>
                      <p><strong>Message: </strong> {$message} </p>
                      <p>This message was sent from the IP Address: {$ipaddress} on {$date} at {$time}</p>";

        mail("EMAIL_ADDRESS","Contact us enquiry",$emailbody,$headers);

    }

    //what we need to return back to our form
    $returndata = array(
        'posted_form_data' => array(
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email,
            'enquiry' => $enquiry,
            'message' => $message
        ),
        'form_ok' => $formok,
        'errors' => $errors
    );


    //if this is not an ajax request
    if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) !== 'xmlhttprequest'){
        //set session variables
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['cf_returndata'] = $returndata;

        //redirect back to form
        header('location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }
}
```

I would be grateful if anyone could provide some pointers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the name of the form element you used to represent the department, just use a switch case to change the delivery address?

It may be worth noting that simpler values, such as `admin_enquiry` rather than Admin / account enquiry may be easier to match against.

```
switch ($select_department)
{
    case "admin_enquiry":
        // Set to email as appropriate
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to build database table (or just confing/php array) like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `departments` (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  email VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY (id)
);
```

Print it as:

```php
$selected = isset( $_POST['department']) ? $_POST['department'] : '';
echo '<select name="department">';
foreach( $db->fetch_all( 'SELECT * FROM departments') as $dep){
    echo '<option value="' . $dep['id'] . '"' .
         (($dep['id'] == $selected) ? 'selected="selected"' : '')
         . '>' . htmlspecialchars( $dep['name']) . '</option>';
}
```

And when sending:

```php
$email = '';
if( !isset( $_POST['department'])){
  $formok = false;
  $errors[] = "Department not send";
} elseif( $row = $db->fetch_row( 'SELECT email FROM departments WHERE id = ?', array( $_POST['department'])){
  $email = $row['email']
} else {
  $formok = false;
  $errors[] = "Invalid department";
}

/// ...

mail( $email, ...);
```